# How to validate DataGridView for Decimal values 0.00 in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am validating my textbox for allowing decimal values ad 12.00, 12.50.
My code is

```
double x;
double.TryParse(tb.Text, out x);
tb.Text = x.ToString("0.00");
```

It will add decimal places in textbox when it leaves. As this I want to add .00 to my datagrid view cell for my particular cell. Thank you

Comment: Try setting `DefaultCellStyle.Format = "###.00";` or maybe `"N2"` for the required column

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If anyone has given you a helpful answer that you find partially or completely solves your problem to your satisfaction, you should mark that answer as correct. [This page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/199700) will tell you how to do that and give general advice about what answers to accept. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to display values up to 2 decimal places in your `DataGridView` Cell

you can try by setting the DefaultCellStyle property of the column to `N2` (2 decimal places)

```
dataGridView1.Columns["YourColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView2_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
   {
       if (this.dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Aidat")
       {
          string deger=(string)e.Value;
          deger = String.Format("{0:0.00}", deger);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks
i use `dataGridView1.Columns["YourColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N";`
this is good and work.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are good enough but you can also design your own function for the same task , The below function will convert 23 to 23.00 , 23.0 to 23.00 , 23. to 23.00 , 23.1 to 23.10 and 23.11 will remain as it is , It is just an example to explain the logic

//This function is used to do the formatting of the float values to two places of decimals

```
    private string fn_decimal_formatting(float val)
    {
        String str = val.ToString();
        int pos = str.IndexOf('.');
        if (pos == -1) //IndexOf returns negative one if . does not found in the string
            str += ".00";
        else if (str.Length == pos + 1)
            str += "00";
        else if (str.Length == pos + 2)
            str += "0";
        else
        {
            int start = 0;
            int end = pos + 2;
            str = str.Substring(start, end + 1);
        }
        return str;            
    }
```